# Updating CSS programmatically in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, stylesheet

I am adjusting an older script to work in IE, Chrome and FF. I got it working in IE and Chrome, but Firefox does not seem to apply the changes to the stylesheets - items which get invisible style do not disappear.

Following code is used now to change the visibility:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=10'>
    <title>BootWiz.log.html</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
    h4 {
        display: none;
        font-size: smaller;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: Green;
    }

    h3 {
        display: none;
        font-size: smaller;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: Blue;
    }

    h2 {
        display: block;
        font-size: smaller;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #7030A0;
        background-color: #EBEBEB
    }

    h1 {
        display: block;
        font-size: smaller;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: Red;
        background-color: #EBEBEB
    }

    .nav {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 100;
        border-top: 0;
        background-color: #FFFFFF
    }

    .cont {
        position: relative;
        top: 30
    }

    .success {
        color: #ffff00;
        background-color: #00cc00
    }

    .failure {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #ff0000
    }

    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var searchDone = false;

    function ChangeVisibility(index, node) {
        if (searchDone) {
            alert('Need to reload the page.');
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
        if (node.checked) {
            document.styleSheets[0].rules[index].style.setProperty('display', 'block');
        } else {
            document.styleSheets[0].rules[index].style.setProperty('display', 'none');
        }
    }

    function Search() {
        .....
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <center>
            <input type='checkbox' onClick='ChangeVisibility(0, this);' />
            <font style='color:Green'>Show Verbose</font>
            <input type='checkbox' onClick='ChangeVisibility(1, this);' />
            <font style='color:Blue'>Show Info</font>
            <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' onClick='ChangeVisibility(2, this);' />
            <font style='color: #7030A0'>Show Warning</font>
            <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' onClick='ChangeVisibility(3, this);' />
            <font style='color: Red'>Show Error</font>
            <input id='search' /><button onclick='Search();'>Search Text</button>
        </center>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <font id='logContents' face='Verdana' size='3'>

            <h2> 2015-08-25 08:27:43  <a class=success>Some Stuff started</a></h2>
```

Comment: Please get rid of deprecated HTML tags (`<center>` and `<font>`) and avoid any inline styles. Use CSS to center and `span` tags for text.

Answer (score 3):

Changing CSS is not what you usually want to do.
Just add a new CSS class

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

And use when you want to hide element.

Comment: Thanks, but it would cause iterating over several hundred thousands of elements to adjust styles, which was tried but takes way too long...

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`document.styleSheets[0].rules[index].style.setProperty('display','block');` through this

`node.style.setProperty('display', 'block');`

Also, I'd like to repeat what @tp4k already wrote: Dynamically adjusting a css isn't the proper way of handling styling. Instead, use separated stylesheets to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: It has to be dynamic adjustment - several hundred thousand of elements of each type.